# Rails routing error after fresh install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I just installed Rails, etc. on a Windows 7 machine.

Created my first app, and am trying to go to the first generated and this is what I get:

```
Routing Error

No route matches "/say/hello"
```

Where say is the app name, and hello is the name of the first view.

Thoughts?

Comment: please reveal to us the content of config/routes.rb file. All routing magic happens here.

Comment: or the result of "rake routes"

Comment: The routes.rb file is the regular default routes file. I have added nothing to it. Everything is commented out.

Comment: yup, that's it. In Rails 3 the default routes are empty. @mark's or @casual answer is probably what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're implementing very simple routes (and since this is your first app, I'm assuming that's what you want!), make sure you've un-commented the last route in routes.rb:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

This will send /say/hello to the `hello` action of the `say` controller.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added route in `config/routes.rb` ?

```
get 'say#hello'
```